# Why "GC:" won't work at the powershell

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I saw [this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms676880%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) which has VB example code to bind to global catalog server by using "GC:" and then get the children of it which would give a GC root to search the GC.

```
Set gc = GetObject("GC:")
For each child in gc
    Set entpr = child
WScript.Echo entpr.Name
Next
```

I tried and it works.

However when I tried to convert this into powershell:

```
$gcRoot = New-Object DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry("GC:")
$gcRoot.Children | foreach { 
                    $root = $_
                    Write-Host "GC root child: " + $root.Name
                 }
```

It doesn't work at all. $gcRoot doesn't get anything. If I tried to echo this on the console, I got this:

```
[DBG]: PS <dir>$gcRoot
The following exception occurred while retrieving member "PSComputerName": "Not implemented" At :line:0 char:0
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use ADSI you can use this (Powershell V1.0):

```
# Access to the RootDSE
$dn1 = New-Object System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry ("GC://192.168.183.138/RootDse","administrateur@societe.fr","test.2011")
$dn1

# Access 
$dn2 = New-Object System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry ("GC://192.168.183.138/dc=societe,dc=fr","administrateur@societe.fr","test.2011")
foreach ($child in $dn2.Children)
{
  $child
}
```

You can also install [AD Quest Cmdlets](http://www.quest.com/powershell/activeroles-server.aspx).

If you are using PowerShell V2.0 (on W2K8R2) you can use Active-Directory module which provide bunch of CmdLets and the `AD:` drive

Comment: The real issue with me is that I need to do a forest wide search, so I need to get the root of the forest. I think that it would be forest name (root domain name), so it would like this GC://forestName. The question is how to get the forest name here? The .NET 2.0 has class System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectory.Forest to get the forest name, however we would like to see if we could use .NET 1.0 here. At VB script, "GC://forestName" would be a children return from query "GC:". So I would like to do the similar thing at power shell

Comment: Right now, we have to stay with power shell 1.0.

Answer (score 0):

Found an example here:
http://www.powershellcommunity.org/Forums/tabid/54/aft/1323/Default.aspx
if it helps.

Comment: thanks for the link. actually I saw this too. Basically I copied that code, however I changed to use forest root domain name for a full forest search instead of just a default domain search. However it requires .NET 2.0 (System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectory name space) and we are trying to see if we could lower that requirements.